# What can I do about baby starvation/dehydration after mother was injured?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm using Masterwork DF. I have embarked as orcs in tundra I have a well that is in the cave filled with fine water and a source of food. Recently one of my orcs have been attacked by some animal. She gave birth beforehand. The baby also has a dad and the mother is now recovering in the hospital with her outer brain broken. The baby is now starving outside in the cold, dehydrated and no one seems to care. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

You can try demolishing the hospital to force her to return to her duties, provided she is ambulatory. If she's not, do your utmost to make her so - soap, splints, the whole hospital thing. Otherwise, there are 3 possible outcomes:

- Mother gets better before her babies die and feeds them
- Babies grow up into children before they die and feem themselves
- Babies die

Comment: Thanks unfortunately though baby died shortly after I posted the question due to magma flooding... Anyway if this comes up again I will try those options and tell you how it goes, thanks. Also I don't think it was possible for her to recover... Well, thanks again anyway. ^^

Comment: This is why you can't worry overly much about babies.  Better to worry about things like magma flooding.